# Creating a list of countries to filter data with in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I very new to earth engine but I can't seem to figure out how to create a list of countries that I can then use to filter larger datasets from. The point of this is that I want to use the Hansen data on forest cover change but only in protected areas in specific countries. I managed to get it to filter one country at a time but doing this separately for each country seems unnecessarily tedious.

```
var myStringArrayGFW = ['gain','lossyear'];
var dataset_name = "UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2015_v1_8"; 
var dataset = ee.Image(dataset_name);
var myStringArray = myStringArrayGFW;
  
var filtered_country = myStringArrayGFW.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME', 'Mexico'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach can be:

```
var filter=['Mexico','Peru','Guinea']//your list
var filtered_country = countries.filter(ee.Filter.inList('ADM0_NAME', filter));

var AOI=hansen.select(myStringArrayGFW).clip(filtered_country)
```

Here an example [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/1c85faa78c19b643572c41663e3c9266)

Comment: ;) As a new contributor and if you find this useful, please consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)